# Template for ios notification by Azure Service Bus Notification Hubs

Tags: azure, notifications, apple-push-notifications, azureservicebus

i am using windows azure Service Bus Notification Hubs for ios

i register my device by following code :

```
SBNotificationHub* hub = [[SBNotificationHub alloc] initWithConnectionString:
                                  @"Endpoint=sb://......" notificationHubPath:@"...."];


        NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet set];
        [set addObject:@"general"];
        [hub registerNativeWithDeviceToken:deviceToken tags:[set copy] completion:^(NSError* error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
                [self.delegate homePopUpViewControllerEnterButtonPress:self];

            }


        }];
```

and sending Notification from .Net Backend by using following code :

```
var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(<connection string>, "<notification hub name>");

IDictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();

properties.Add("badge", "1");
properties.Add("alert", "This is Test Text");
properties.Add("sound", "bingbong.aiff");

hubClient.SendTemplateNotification(properties,  "general");
```

i able to receive notification but my problem is : notification does not have any property that  i added , no sound , no badge ...

if you can please help me

references : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj927168.aspx

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You registered for native notifications but then you are sending a template notification.
If you want to send native (this will require additional sends if you want to reach devices on different platforms) you have to use

```
hub.SendAppleNativeNotification(
    "{ \"aps\": { \"alert\": \"This is my alert message for iOS!\"}}", "tag");
```

Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html for the iOS payload format.

Alternatively, you can register for template notifications with:

```
NSString* template = @"{aps: {alert: \"$(myToastProperty)\"}}";
[hub registerTemplateWithDeviceToken:deviceToken 
                                name:@"myToastRegistration"
                    jsonBodyTemplate:template
                      expiryTemplate:nil
                                tags:nil 
                          completion:^(NSError* error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error registering for notifications: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Using a template like:

```
{
   “aps”: {
       “alert”: “$(alert)”
   }
}
```

Then you can send notifications using hub.SendTemplateNotification like you are already doing.

For more information regarding the difference between template and native please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj927170.aspx

Comment: Thanks Elio
by Running this line :
hub.SendAppleNativeNotification("{ \"alert\": \"This is my alert message for iOS!\"}", "tag");

i got this error:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The supplied notification payload is invalid.TrackingId:3d8e3198-223b-4245-ad2f-aebd4a59e4ae_G7,TimeStamp:7/10/2013 2:51:46 AM

Comment: Sorry the alert property has to be inside an "aps" element as shown in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html
E.g. {"aps":{"alert": "Hello
!"}}